# Issue on Using LOAD DATA INFILE in Production Server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This code is working fine for me to load a huge .csv file into `ecolo-dis-tbl` table in Localhost using PHPMyAdmin and Wampserver

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Data/Spreatsheets/Data-Single.csv' 
INTO TABLE `ecolo-dis-tbl` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Now can some one please let me know how I can address the file in production server like Godaddy? I mean instead of `C:/Data/Spreatsheets/` what path should use if I load the file into the root

Comment: You'll need to find out what file path your root directory is in. It should be saying it somewhere in your control panel

Answer (score 0):

Using phpMyAdmin you can select the Import tab and work with the file directly from your local machine. To use the SQL code you've posted here, you'll first have to upload the file to your production database server by means of SSH, FTP, or whatever other way you put files on the server. Note that for some hosts the web server is on a different machine from the database server, so you have to make sure they go on the database server. Then just use the new path (maybe something like `/home/suffii/Data-Single.csv`) in place of `C:/Data/Spreatsheets/Data-Single.csv`.